# Setting breakpoints in a JavaScript file (run in IE) in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a web page as part of an ASP .Net application. When I include my JavaScript within a script node in the page I can set breakpoints in the JavaScript in Visual Studio and when I debug the project (which launches the page locally in IE) the breakpoint is successfully caught in Visual Studio and I can use it to inspect variables, step through, and do all the usual Visual Studio debugging stuff. However, when I move my JavaScript to a separate script file breakpoints stop working, and I see the message 'The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.'

I know I could take advantage of the browser's debugging tools but how do I get Visual Studio to hit breakpoints in a JavaScript file in an ASP .Net application?

It would also be good to understand why the breakpoint works when the JavaScript is included in a script node within the HTML page, and fails when it is moved to a separate JavaScript file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the point I made in the question about having the JavaScript in the HTML file versus in a separate script file may have been misleading. It tried copying it back and it still did not work!

I have made two changes and now it is fixed (though I am not sure which one fixed it).

Firstly I checked the closing curly brackets on each function in my JavaScript (after reading [robert4's answer to What can be the reasons for JavaScript breakpoint is not hit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22105962/575530)) and added a missing semi-colon after the function I'd recently added.

Secondly I held down the `Ctrl` key and clicked `refresh` in the IE launched by Visual Studio which should force a page reload (instead of loading from IE's cache).

I'm assuming that the second of these changes fixed things but I've included the first to just-in-case it proves useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

1) First open Visual studio -> select your project in solution explorer.-> Right click and choose option "browse with" then set IE as default browser.

2) Now open IE. Go to,
Tools -> Internet option -> Advance -> uncheck the checkbox having "Disable Script Debugging (Internet Explorer) and then click Apply and OK and you are done.

3) Now you can set breakpoints in your JS file and then hit the debug button in VS.

[image]

Comment: Step 1 doesn't work, [here's the screenshot](https://www.flickr.com/photos/dumbledad/16493090390/) of my right-click menu that has no "browse with" option. Step 2 was there, the box was checked and I unchecked it, but even after restarting the laptop and rebuilding the solution it has had no effect whatever, the breakpoint still fails and displays the same error.

Comment: I'll edit the question to add this, but it would be great if the answer could also explain why the breakpoint works when the JavaScript is included in a script node within the HTML page, and fails when it is moved to a separate JavaScript file.